# spell check  text editor plugin

Tags: javascript

how can I spell check in my text area, I have dictionary which is provided by Javascript spell check but its not working it contains one `Testinstall.htm` while installing this I got struck in  server test,i dont want to use third party tool is there any other way to achieve spell check for text area

`software:- javascript,html,sql`

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/demo

Answer (score 0):

Refer this. It will help....

[tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is a solid RTE that can use ASpell or PSpell for its spell checking plugin